# Research statement: separate bibliographies for your own publications and the rest of the literature?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, faculty-application, tenure-track, research-statement

When writing a research statement, is it a good idea to create two reference lists: one exclusively for your own work and one for the rest of the relevant literature that you may want to cite?

On the one hand, I think it's a good idea to have a cleanly presented list of your own publications without having them "too scattered" across a larger bibliography. On the other hand, I'm worried that the separation may look weird.

Bonus question: in case, what title should I give to the list of my own papers (as opposed to "Bibliography/References" for the rest)?

---

Example: https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/butkovsky/rs.pdf

Comment: I've never seen such a format, is there someplace you saw it? If so, you could consider adding it to the question.

Comment: @AppliedAcademic Here for example: https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/butkovsky/rs.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think two lists can be helpful, in fact some grant submission processes encourage doing it that way. If you are using enumerated rather than harvard style (author, year) then be sure to start the numbering from where you left off after your own list (this is pretty easy to automate if your CV is in latex.) Depending on the dialect of English used where you are applying, you could say something like: "List of Publications" or "Candidate's Publications" and then "Further References". If you don't put the two lists right after each other, put a footnote under "Further References" with the page number to find the citations for your own publications.

If you don't have a strict page limit, it's probably easier just to have a highlighted list of publications and then redundantly include them in your ordinary reference page. And also, you could always just say "see CV for full list of publications."

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, my motivation for the question was that it looked easier/clearer to say "In [Myself2022], we blabla... In [1], this result blabla..." where [1] points to a paper by someone else